# Astro hydration saying not working on renderer

Tags: reactjs, tsx, solid-js, astrojs

Why I keep getting this error message saying no renderer for react and solidjs ? also why the React component didn't appears on the screen? Below price supposed to be appear a button "add to cart"

[image]

The errors are

```
18:37:01 [renderer] C:/Users/flyingduck/Desktop/astro-frontend-masters/src/components/add-to-cart.tsx No renderer installed for react. Try adding `@astrojs/react` to your project.
18:37:01 [renderer] C:/Users/flyingduck/Desktop/astro-frontend-masters/src/components/cart.tsx No renderer installed for solid-js. Try adding `@astrojs/solid-js` to your project.
```

This is my `astro.config.mjs`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

import solidJs from '@astrojs/solid-js';
import react from '@astrojs/react';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [solidJs(), react()]
});
```

**cart.tsx**

```
import { useStore } from '@nanostores/solid';
import { cart, removeItemFromCart, subtotal } from '../stores/cart';
import styles from './cart.module.css';
import { Show, createSignal } from 'solid-js';

function formatCurrency(amount: number) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        currency: 'usd',
        style: 'currency',
    }).format(amount);
}

const EmptyState = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <p class={styles.icon}>
                <span role="img" aria-label="hot dog">
                    
                </span>
            </p>
            <p class={styles.empty}>
                Your cart is empty! Add a sandwich kit or two and give flavor a chance.
            </p>
        </>
    );
};

const CheckoutNotice = () => {
    return <p class={styles.notice}>Checkout is not implemented yet.</p>;
};

export const Cart = () => {
    const [showNotice, setShowNotice] = createSignal(false);
    const $cart = useStore(cart);
    const $subtotal = useStore(subtotal);

    return (
        <aside class={styles.cart}>
            <h2>Your Cart</h2>
            <Show when={Object.values($cart()).length > 0} fallback={<EmptyState />}>
                <ul class={styles.items}>
                    {Object.values($cart()).map((entry) => {
                        if (!entry) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        return (
                            <li class={styles.item}>
                                <span class={styles.quantity}>{entry.quantity}</span>
                                <span class={styles.name}>{entry.item.title}</span>
                                <span class={styles.remove}>
                                    <button
                                        title="remove item"
                                        onClick={() => removeItemFromCart(entry.item.id)}
                                    >
                                        &times;
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                <span class={styles.price}>
                                    {formatCurrency(entry.item.price)}
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>

                <div class={styles.details}>
                    <p class={styles.subtotal}>
                        <span class={styles.label}>Subtotal:</span>{' '}
                        {formatCurrency($subtotal())}
                    </p>
                    <p class={styles.shipping}>
                        <span class={styles.label}>Shipping:</span>
                        <del>$10.00</del>
                        <ins>FREE</ins>
                    </p>
                    <p class={styles.total}>
                        <span class={styles.label}>Total:</span>{' '}
                        {formatCurrency($subtotal())}
                    </p>

                    <p class={styles.checkout}>
                        <button class="big-link" onClick={() => setShowNotice(true)}>
                            Check Out
                        </button>
                    </p>

                    <Show when={showNotice()}>
                        <CheckoutNotice />
                    </Show>
                </div>
            </Show>
        </aside>
    );
};
```

**add-to-cart.tsx**

```
/** @jsxImportSource react */

import { addItemToCart } from '../stores/cart';

export const AddToCart = ({ item }: { item: ShopItem }) => {
    return (
        <button className="big-link" onClick={() => addItemToCart(item)}>
            Add To Cart
        </button>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed with config, migrate to astro v3

First, config

```js
// astro.config.mjs
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";

import react from "@astrojs/react";
import solid from "@astrojs/solid-js";

export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    solid({
      include: ["**/solid/*"],
    }),
    react({
      include: ["**/react/*"],
    }),
  ],
});
```

Second you need to setup folder structure with Astro v3 guideline, CREATE NEW subfolder like this:

- `/component/react/[...React components here]` => `[add-to-cart.tsx]`
- `/component/solid/[...Solid components here]` => `[cart.module.css, cart.tsx]`

Then, you need fix your import.

Comment: This worked and I didn't had to migrate to astro 3

Answer (score 2):

Astro 3.0 introduced changes to the way projects use multiple JSX frameworks.

> Astro v3.0 now requires you to specify which framework to use for your files with new include and exclude integration config options when you have multiple JSX framework integrations installed.

Split your components into different directories depending on the JSX framework, then update your config to include these files.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import react from '@astrojs/react';
import solid from '@astrojs/solid-js';

export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    react({
      include: ['**/react/*']
    }),
    solid({
      include: ['**/solid/*'],
    }),
  ]
});
```

- [Upgrade to V3](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/upgrade-to/v3/#changed-multiple-jsx-framework-configuration)
- [Combining multiple JSX frameworks - SolidJS](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/solid-js/#combining-multiple-jsx-frameworks)

Comment: I did that but the react part still gives me the same error, so I had to downgrade both solid and react just for a precaution and it still works. The version of react to `@astrojs/react@2.1.1` and the version of solid to `@astrojs/react@2.1.0`